# App after a while crash with TokenRefresher exception

Tags: java, android

I have this problem, which I tried to solve without success.
I am using cloud messaging in Firebase (FCM) to send push notification to particular device. I deployed the function and everything is working fine, only that after every 4 or 5 minutes my app always crash with

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: TokenRefresher.

I am storing the tokenID in my firestore document every time the user open the app (after the splash screen load) and also when user login.
Code down bellow is how i'm storing it.

I need help to understand what's going on.

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
 @Override
 public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {

 //Get device token id here
 String deviceToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();

  //Store device token id in user document                         
 firebaseFirestore.collection("Users")

   .document(userID).update("token_id", deviceToken)

   .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

   @Override

  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

   if(task.isSuccessful()){

    //On success direct user to main activity                                            
   Intent toMain = new Intent(SignIn.this, MainActivity.class);

   toMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    startActivity(toMain);

     finish();

     Bungee.fade(SignIn.this);

  }else{

  Toast.makeText(SignIn.this,Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException())
  .getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
   });
  }
 });
```

Here's my gradle file

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

  com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config
   .disableVersionCheck = true

android {

compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ibrahimsahko.zee"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
  }
}

  dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.Binary-Finery:Bungee:master-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.irfaan008:IRBottomNavigationView:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.gauravk.bubblenavigation:bubblenavigation:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.github.hsmnzaydn:imagezoom:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: send the token from the newToken method in your messageReceiver class

Comment: what do you mean by newToken method

Comment: see this
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/375c1ae5ec9000ee71b93cee409086e27d774bdb/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L106-L120

Answer (score 0):

as [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken()) says

getToken() method is deprecated.
In favour of `getInstanceId()`.

You can use `FirebaseMessagingService` for receive token

like this

```
public class HandleFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService 
  {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Applog.d("FCM", "FirebaseToken: " + s);

}}
```